# FFI error when running "shopify theme dev"

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, shopify, themes

Whenever i try to run this command in git bash i get this error

```
── external error ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Error coming from `bundle install`

Command failed with exit code 5: bundle install
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/e
xt/ffi_c
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in
/usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDK
s/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Pla
tforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi...        
no
checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes  
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/e
xt/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230724-17792-b9whme
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230724-17792-b9whme clean

current directory: C:/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/e
xt/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230724-17792-b9whme
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230724-17792-b9whme
generating ffi_c-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `mkdir -p "/c/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/e
xt/ffi_c/libffi-x64-mingw-ucrt"
""/c/Users/Oliver(D)"'
make: *** [libffi.mk:6: "/c/Users/Oliver] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5  
for
inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Oliver
Taylor/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mi
ngw-ucrt/3.2.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:118:in    
`run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:52:in `block
 in
make'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in     
`each'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in     
`make'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:41:
in
`build'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:186:in      
`build_extension'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:220:in      
`block
in build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:217:in    
`each'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:217:in      
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:845:in        
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72
:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28
:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:202:in   
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:5
4:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:1
6:in
`install_from_spec'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer
.rb:156:in
`do_install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer
.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in   
process_queue'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'    
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2   
levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot        
continue.

In Gemfile:
  listen was resolved to 3.7.1, which depends on
    rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
      ffi
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I can run the command on zsh and it'll run but i have to run it again to see any changes i've been trying everything not sure if anyone can help

I've tried running the command sudo shopify theme dev same issues i've been back and forth with chatgpt to try and troubleshoot the issue i've uninstalled and reinstalled the shopify cli a few times ruby aswell installed the LTS version of Node.js i've tried other things but they've been lost to the ether at this point

Comment: can you try running it with sudo? `sudo shopify theme dev`